# Populate tableview using contacts framework

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, tableview, contacts

I want to populate a tableview with contact details that I have entered in the app.

first i have a table view controller that will show the list of entered contacts. its swift file looks like this.

```
    import Contacts
    import ContactsUI


class thecontacts: UITableViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate,    UIPickerViewDelegate {

        let contacts = CNMutableContact()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

    return cell
}
```

I want to populate this from another view controller. I want to populate this tableview with a persons name, and have it as a contact in the tableview. This view controllers swift file is:

```
       import Contacts



      class newContact: UIViewController {


//outlets
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

var tableViewController: newContact? = nil




override func viewDidLoad() {

}

@IBAction func addBuddy(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contacts = CNMutableContact()
    contacts.nickname = nameTextField!.text!;
    contacts.emailAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label: nil, value: emailTextField.text!)]

    self.tableViewController?.addBuddy(contacts)

    dismiss()
}

func dismiss(){
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

      }
```

my tableViewController file is called thecontacts.swift. My new contact details viewController is called newContacts.swift.

the problem I have is that the details I enter into the newContact file are not appearing in my thecontacts table view.

Comment: reload the tableview after adding contacts. use the code like this tableview.reloadData()

Comment: That did not seem to work